# webpack replace a placeholder with the bundle hash in index.htm

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

My goal is replace a string like

```
<!--configjs-->
```

with

```
<script src="/api/config?bundle-hash"></script>
```

in my index.html file

I'm using https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter

```
plugins: [
    // Injects bundles in your index.html instead of wiring all manually.
    // It also adds hash to all injected assets so we don't have problems
    // with cache purging during deployment.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'client/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      hash: true
    })
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)

Configure the plugin, (I think you want to turn inject to false to give you greater control).

```
// webpack.config.js
plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
    {
       inject : false,
       template : 'index.html'
    }
)]
```

And within your html template call out the chunk by name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files['bundle-hash'].entry %>"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not entirely sure of your exact needs, but you may be able to just use the plugin defaults and get what you're looking for.  The plugin can take an existing html file as a template, and inject CSS in the head, and scripts in the body. In cases where you want more control, you can do what I'm proposing above.

Comment: Thanks @cgatian but it doesn't work the replace is missing both with inject : false or inject : true but I have to set to 'body' to manage the script tag I mean if I peep into html source I still see <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files['bundle-hash'].entry %>

Comment: I've updated my post with the current HtmlWebpackPlugin set up

Comment: I had to use `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.entry`. Just put `<%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin.files) %>` into you html and see for yourself how the path should be.

Comment: Do you know of any webpack plugin that can replace `html-webpack-plugin` like placeholders with variables, but on an arbitrary file?